# Echo first result from MYSQL differently than all the other results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table in which contains video titles, video embed html, video description, and video thumbnails. I want it to output the first entry as;

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM entries");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['title'];
  echo $row['html'];
  echo $row['desc'];
}
```

and after that, I would like it to output the next five entries as

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM entries");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['title'];
  echo "<a href='". $row['id'] . "'><img src='" . $row['thu'] . "'></a>";
}
```

however I have no idea how to do this. I am kind of a newb when it comes to mysql. Any help would be appreciated.

I have looked at other similar questions but none of them really fit the bill.

Answer (score 2):

Poor man's solution would be something like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM entries");
$first = true;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  if ($first) {
    echo $row['title'], $row['html'], $row['desc'];
    $first = false;
    continue 2;
  }

  echo $row['title'], "<a href='{$row[id]}'><img src='{$row[thu]}'></a>";  
}
```

(As explained in PHP chatroom)

Answer (score 1):

Since `mysqli_fetch_array()` gets you a row, you can use it before the `while()` without a problem like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM entries");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['title'];
//etc.
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['title'];
  echo "<a href='". $row['id'] . "'><img src='" . $row['thu'] . "'></a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Track it with a sentinel value

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  if($i == 0){
    //first iteration
    echo $row['title'];
    echo $row['html'];
    echo $row['desc']; 
  }else{
    echo $row['title'];
    echo "<a href='". $row['id'] . "'><img src='" . $row['thu'] . "'></a>";
  }
  $i++;//increment value
}
```